# What is the meaning of `[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]` in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

```
x=[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]
print(x[1][0][1])
```

***could you please tell me the output and how's it obtained***

Comment: index to the second row(1), then to the first(0th) row of that, then grab the first element(0)..

Comment: Have you tried printing `x`, `x[1]`, `x[1][0]` first? If you understand what slicing `[]` does, this is just multiple applcations of it.

Comment: Why asking us the output of **your code** while you can ask the Python interpreter?

Comment: @norok2  sorry for trouble but iam bit confused with the indexes.

Comment: @VinodYadav I am just trying to help you ask a better question.

Comment: @norok2 for sure brother, will be doing better with your advice, and thank u

Answer (score 2):

`list[i]` takes the (i+1)-th element of the list, so `[0]` means the first element and `[1]` the second element from the list. Counting in computer science always starts at 0.

`x[1]` = `[[5,6],[7,8]]`

`x[1][0]` = `[5,6]`

`x[1][0][1]` = `6`

Answer (score 2):

You can visualize `x=[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]` like this to understand the nesting:

```
x = [
        [ #0
            [ #0
                1, #0
                2  #1
            ],
            
            [ #1
                3, #0
                4  #1
            ]
        ],
    
        [ #1 -> x[1] access this
            [ #0 -> then .[0]
                5, #0
                6  #1 -> finally .[1]
            ],
            
            [ #1
                7, #0
                8  #1
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
|1, 2| |5, 6|
|3, 4| |7, 8|
```

x[1] points to the second matrix, [0] means first row, [1] means second value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be 6. The way it works is that you are accessing a small part of the list which you specify inside the square brackets. The idea is that every element that is inside a list is assigned an index value. the index values are assigned from 0 to how ever elements there are in that given list. So in our case you have two items `[[1,2],[3,4]]` which is assigned 0 and `[[5,6],[7,8]]`which is assigned 1. So in your print statement the first set of square brackets is accessing the second element i.e `[[5,6],[7,8]]`

Now the for your second set of square brackets we must look into `[[5,6],[7,8]]` for the first element as the first element has an index of zero. So in this case you would get `[5,6]`.

Finally for the third set of your square brackets you must access the second element i.e (cause it is the index of 1) of `[5,6]` which is 6...and hence you get your answer

REMEBER: LIST INDEX ALWAYS START FROM ZERO